# CSS active style

Tags: html, css

I need to have the same hover effect to be applied on the current state for the main menu item (sub items already have the current state)

```
<ul id="left-menu"><li><a href="#">
<h3>Improve Your Free Web Page <span style="float:right">&#9660;</span></h3>
</a>
<ul>
  <li class="current"><a href="upload_picture.html">Upload Your Picture(s)</a></li>
  <li><a href="upload_video.html">Upload Your Video(s)</a></li>
  <li><a href="upload_logo.html">Upload Your Logo</a></li>
  <li><a href="upload_logotype.html">Upload Your Logotype</a></li>
  <li><a href="update_tagline.html">Update Your Tagline</a></li>
  <li><a href="describe_business.html">Describe Your Business</a></li>
  <li><a href="offer.html">Add Offer(s)</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVRHA/)

Comment: So what have you tried? Also this couldvé been dan by a simple google. 
http://bit.ly/137uqBy

Answer (score 0):

Usually with submenu's people create a list in a list. If you add the "current" class to the outer list, you can style it with css properly.